# T is tues & TH is thurs. preg_match mixup?

Tags: php, preg-match

```
$garbageday = MTH //(Monday & Thursday)
<h2><small>Garbage Day:</small> <?php if (preg_match('/M/',$garbageday)) echo 'Monday';
if (preg_match('/T/',$garbageday)) echo 'Tuesday';
if (preg_match('/W/',$garbageday)) echo 'Wednesday';
if (preg_match('/TH/',$garbageday)) echo 'Thursday';
if (preg_match('/F/',$garbageday)) echo 'Friday';
if (preg_match('/S/',$garbageday)) echo 'Saturday';
if (preg_match('/NONE/',$garbageday)) echo 'Collected Privately';?>
```

Outputs: Garbage Day: MondayTuesdayThursday

How do i code this so that Tuesday wont show every time its Thursday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure there is no `H` that follows `T`:

```
~T(?!H)~
```

Or in your code it would be

```
if (preg_match('/T(?!H)/', $garbageday)) {
    echo 'Tuesday';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want or have to do it this way, you just need to ignore a T followed by an H when checking to see if it's Tuesday:

```
if (preg_match('/T[^H]/',$garbageday)) echo 'Tuesday';
```

However, I recommend adopting the traditional one-letter date code for Thursday — **R** — instead of mixing one- and two-letter codes.

Comment: Thanx a million! I would but I'm using json output from nyc's api

Answer (score -1):

Do the /TH/ test first, and use an if/else.

```
     if (preg_match('/TH/',$garbageday)) echo 'Thursday';
     else if (preg_match('/T/',$garbageday)) echo 'Tuesday';
     else if (preg_match('/W/',$garbageday)) echo 'Wednesday';
     else if (preg_match('/F/',$garbageday)) echo 'Friday';
     else if (preg_match('/S/',$garbageday)) echo 'Saturday';
     else if (preg_match('/NONE/',$garbageday)) echo 'Collected Privately';?>
```

Comment: Thanx 4 quick reply! The problem is that now it shows Thursday only when it should show Monday Thursday

Comment: I misread.  I did not see you needed more than one garbage day.  You'll have to do a "T and Not H" `/T(?!H)/` as others have said already.